# How to display data based on logged in users in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to display data in Laravel based on data that has been input, currently I can display user data but cannot display other data based on the ID that was input, for example I have input child data that is linked to user data

**User Controller**

```
 public function getAnak(){
        $dataanak = DB::table('users as I')
                    ->select('A.id_anak', 'A.nama_anak','A.tempat_lhr','A.tgl_lhr','A.bb_lahir','A.tb_lahir','A.jenis_kelamin','A.jenis_persalinan','A.tempat_persalinan','A.dokter','A.NIK_anak')
                    ->leftjoin('anaks as A', 'I.id', '=', 'A.id_ibu')
                    ->get();
                    
        return view('user.dataanak', compact('dataanak'));
    }
```

So I want to display child data based on the logged in user, currently I can only display user data as follows

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/002/534/006/small/social-media-chatting-online-blank-profile-picture-head-and-body-icon-people-standing-icon-grey-background-free-vector.jpg" alt="avatar"
              class="rounded-circle img-fluid" style="width: 150px;">
            <h5 class="my-3"></h5>
            <p class="text-muted mb-1">Ny. {{ auth()->user()->nama_ibu }}</p>
            <p class="text-muted mb-4">{{ auth()->user()->NIK }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

can anyone help this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the child data based on the user's ID. Try the following.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function getAnak()
{
    $userId = Auth::id();
    $dataanak = DB::table('anaks')
        ->select('id_anak', 'nama_anak', 'tempat_lhr', 'tgl_lhr', 
            'bb_lahir', 'tb_lahir', 'jenis_kelamin',
            'jenis_persalinan', 'tempat_persalinan', 'dokter', 'NIK_anak')
        ->where('id_ibu', $userId)
        ->get();

    return view('user.dataanak', compact('dataanak'));
}
```

**View**

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h1>Child Data</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date of Birth</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($dataanak as $child)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $child->nama_anak }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $child->tgl_lhr }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $child->jenis_kelamin }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: how to display it in blade.php

Comment: @LanzKing See above.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me, thank you master